# Deploying Node w/ Express App to DigitalOcean: App Won't Run On Port 3000

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, deployment

My Express app is on a Ubuntu 16.04 DigitalOcean server with Node installed.

As a basic test I ran my server.js file with this command:

`node server.js`

Then I tested the file with:

`curl http://localhost:3000`

however this returned `Cannot GET /`.

I tested a separate app.js file **without** Express using a simple HTTP server and it returned anything I wanted regardless of port number. In other words, it isn't a firewall issue.

Express module is installed.

I think it may be a problem with my Express implementation. Here is my server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log("express has started on port 3000");
});
```

Any advice on how else to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: You don't have a route in your `server.js`. Have you tried with `app.get('/', function(req,res) { res.send('ok') }` ?

Comment: This fixed the `Cannot GET /` however how do I log something back via curl? With the simple HTTP server I was using res.write and console.log doesn't return anything via curl. Thanks for your help, I'm new to express :)

Comment: Well `res.send('ok')` should output in curl `ok`. If you want to log to the console instead you can use `res.send('ok'); console.log('request received');`.

Comment: Yeah it's the weirdest thing because it doesn't output anything.. There's no error now but there's no output either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reddit /u/bdenzer helped me out with this answer that works. Needed to point to a file to see an output via CURL. Adding this right about the `app.listen` yields an output. You need to create a file with text in it in the same directory as server.js of course. Also you need to import this at the top of server.js to serve the text file: `let path = require('path');`

```
 app.get('/', (req, res) => { 
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'hello.txt')); 
 });
```